# How can I allow only one user to run a specific command?

Tags: sudo

I want to block all users on a CentOS system from running a specific command and only allow one, specific user to run it.

For example, only the `test` user can run `svnadmin create test1`. Other users should not be allowed to run this.

I've already added the following line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
ALL (ALL) !/usr/bin/svnadmin, !/bin/svnadmin
```

but other users can still run `svnadmin create`.

Comment: When you say "restrict a command _to_ all users except one", is the one user allowed or not allowed to use the command?

Comment: Does `svnadmin create` require root access? Can a regular user execute it?

Comment: @terdon It depends where the Subversion repository is created, but the tool itself does not intrinsicly require elevated privilegies.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, exactly. Which is why I figure storing the repo in a place that requires root access might be a reasonable way of blocking non-root users from creating  new Subversion users (I'm guessing that's what the command does, or perhaps create new repos).

Comment: Your above command would only work if all your users were in the `sudo/wheel` group.  Can you not host your project on say a Private/Corporate GitHub etc.

Comment: root privileges seem like a very bad thing to involve in this. I don't know `svnadmin` so I can't say if it can be abused out of the box, but if it can't you'll just be a simple bug away from suddenly having a way to become to root.

Comment: @Kusalananda That is correct only one user allowed to perform this command other can't.

Comment: @terdon Regular user execute it